# Software and hardware required for SQL Server + ASP.NET web app

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, server, intranet

The idea is to run sql server database and create asp.net web application for the database, so users could access it using Internet Explorer. It's a small company internal network. We want to use free software.

Can you, please, tell how to build it from scratch. What OS is needed, how to install and configure all the stuff, IIS etc... I've little idea about it, any help would be great.

Sql server express + SSMS

Visual Web Developer express

**EDIT**

Ok, Windows server 2012 seems to be installed already. So OS is not the question. So now the choice is Windows server, IIS, .NET, SQL server.

I just don't know how to ask it in more details, I'm not sure about the process of starting a server and a database in a company... I can develop, but never started the whole thing from the very beginning.

Comment: The question is very broad and opinion based, so you will not most likely get the answer you are looking for here. If yih have more specific programming related issues, they can be addressed. But for software recommendation, configuration help etc you will have to find some other venue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question should be more targeted, but I can point some key points to help you get started:

**1) Sql** - You can work with [SQL Server Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx), as long as its [limitations](http://sqlknowledge.com/2014/04/sql-2014-express-edition-limitations/) do not stop you. Basically, max memory and max database size can be the worst enemies here. Also, I had trouble in restoring database from "normal" instances (some non-supported features will block the restore)

**2) IDE** - [Visual Studio Community Edition 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) is a powerful IDE. I have used intensively for personal use and I am happy with it. The only problem I have is some hangs during debugging. Pay attention to its license limitations, though:

```
In non-enterprise organizations, up to five users can use Visual Studio Community. In enterprise organizations (meaning those with >250 PCs or >$1 Million US Dollars in annual revenue), no use is permitted beyond the open source, academic research, and classroom learning environment scenarios described above.
```

**3) Web server** - `IIS` is a natural choice when you are developing Web apps under Windows. It is quite easy to install (optional feature in Windows Server) and to perform basic configurations (bindings, application pools, web apps etc.). More details can be found [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-85/installing-iis-85-on-windows-server-2012-r2).

**4) Project type** - I am familiar with [ASP.NET MVC5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc5) and I can recommend it as a project type for Web apps. Allows a modern application architecture and works nicely of things like Bootstrap (use it by default), `jQuery`, `AngularJs`, `auto mappers`, `dependency injection` (used `Ninject`). Also has nice features such as `attribute routing` and `authentication filters`.

**5) Development cycle** - there are many things to say here, but using `MVC 5` allows a fast development cycle: `publish` -> copy-paste content (except .configs) over target Web app folder and the Web app will run using the new code. This is one point that was lacking in ASP.NET 5 (next version).

Using this technology stack requires Windows OS, which is not free, but its price looks reasonable to me.

I think the most important discriminant should be existing experience of your team. If most of you have experience with `SQL Server,` `.NET`, `IIS` etc., than paying licenses might be less expensive that learning to work with other technologies (there is actually a price associated with learning curve, so nothing is really free, if not previously known).

**NOTE:** I had the opportunity to attend a course with hands on labs about transition to `ASP.NET 5`. It is a great technology that is still under development. However, we had some unanswered questions regarding the deployment. E.g. currently deployment under `IIS` is very easy, but doing this in vNext is far from being trivial.

http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext

Comment: Thanks. Very polite answer. So, to conclude, I install windows server 2010/2012, install IIS that comes with it, install SQL server express, install visual studio 2010 express and should be ok with software? One more thing. If Windows server 2012 is already running, can I activate IIS somehow and how to make my web app available in local network? ... if it's not too big question)

Comment: @SWA - yes, use SQL Express 2014 and Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 to benefit from the latest features. If Windows Server 2012 is already installed, it can be easily activated: check [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/installing-iis-8-on-windows-server-2012) or [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-85/installing-iis-85-on-windows-server-2012-r2) for step by step instructions.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look through. If you have any input for a beginner, please tell me. If what you told is enough, then fine.

Answer (score 3):

Sql Server is not free. Go with something like MySQL instead if an ER database is what you want.

There is a free version of SQL Server, named SQL Server Express, but this has some limitations, including:

- Constrained to a single CPU (in 2012, this limitation has been
  changed to "The lesser of one socket or four cores", so
  multi-threading is possible)
- 1GB RAM (Same in 2008/2012)
- 4GB database size (raised to 10GB in SQL 2008 R2 and SQL 2012) per
  database

If this suits your needs, then you're fine. As far as ASP.Net goes, as well as SQL Server, they both require a Windows Server license, which is also not free. You may want to consider Linux as an alternative and then:

- Write your ASP.Net site using ASP.Net Core 1.0 (which runs on Kestrel/Linux)
- Use MySql database

This way you end up with:

- Free OS
- Free Database
- Free WebSite
- Cost of hardware.

Good luck :)

Comment: You are very self-contradicting. ASP.NET requires server license, but can be run on Linux for free? It doesn't require any server license on any platform. SQL Server is not free, but then you mention a free version? And as an opinion, I would rather take PostgreSQL as an alternative, it has much better standards compliance and is much easier to work with.

Comment: ASP.Net is an opensource framework for writing websites and webapis using C# and html. You can run it in IIS (which requires a server) or you can run it with Kestrel (free, exists on Linux), or even as a self-contained app. To do this, you need to create an ASP.Net CORE, which is the new shiny from Microsoft. Same with SQL Server. USUALLY you need more than what the Express edition gives you, so for a business need, I Would not choose it. It is meant for developer testing only

Comment: IIS is available on workstation versions also. ASP.NET can be run on Mono using older versions also, no need for Core version. Though it's much nicer to use. SQL Express is not (only) for development, it's for smaller use, which in this case seems appropriate since they mentioned small use.